# Airflow's DataprocPySparkOperator time out after one hour (using Google Cloud Composer)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, timeout, airflow, google-cloud-dataproc, google-cloud-composer

I have had this problem for several weeks now, so I wanted to know if someone else has encountered the same issue: I have a pipeline orchestrated by **Cloud Composer** (Google Cloud Platform's managed version of Apache Airflow). I have some tasks coded in PySpark that need to be executed on a Cloud Dataproc cluster.

As a result, I use the **DataprocPySparkOperator**. It works perfectly fine for most tasks. Nonetheless, as soon as a task's execution duration exceeds one hour, the task is (almost) systematically marked as "failed" on the Airflow UI, *although the task is still running fine on Dataproc*.

I have done a fair amount of research on the Internet, and read about the visibility timeout of Celery (the mandatory executor for Cloud Composer) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27310899/celery-is-rerunning-long-running-completed-tasks-over-and-over/36873407#36873407). I also read that there previously was a similar issue with the Kubernetes Operator due to the Kubernetes client itself (for instance [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52978893/why-shouldnt-you-run-kubernetes-pods-for-longer-than-an-hour-from-composer)).

Nonetheless I never found a post dealing with a timeout issue related to DataprocPySparkOperator. I have tried changing the image version of Composer and setting the visibility timeout to 10 hours in the Airflow configuration overrides, with mitigated results.

**EDIT**
It seems like changing the visibility timeout of Celery in the Airflow configuration (see [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uh38g.png)
) has solved the issue, although I need to wait it out a few more runs to confirm the issue is effectively solved. I would still like to understand why this issue appeared only for Dataproc, and how this visibility timeout influences the reliability of Airflow.

Comment: Can you add logs please, will allow us to help you better

Comment: I don't have logs saved right now I'll try to get them if I encounter the issue again.

Comment: I am using airflow (Cloud Composer) with long running (3-4h) pyspark jobs without any issues. The DAG is running daily for months. I suggest you to upgrade your Composer version to the last and avoid changing aitflow.cfg.